# Hibernate findOne doesn't work the first time

Tags: java, hibernate

The following code throws a NullPointerException when `id` matches a form revision in the database:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public FormRevision getFormRevision(Long id) {
    FormRevision formRevision = formRevisionDao.findOne(id);
    formRevision.fillLazyCollections();//NullPointerException happens here for some form revisions
    return formRevision;
}
```

This happens because the `formRevisionDao.findOne(id)` is returning `null` for certain form revisions.  This does not happen for every form revision, but for the ones it does happen for it is consistent, and will fail every time.

**Additional Info:**

The formRevisionDAO object is auto-generated by Hibernate and looks like the following

```
@Repository()
public interface IFormRevisionDAO extends JpaRepository<FormRevision, Long> {}
```

The generated hibernate query doesn't look like it could cause the cause.  It only has left outer joins, and the where clause is only "id = ?".  Also, this query works for other form revisions.

It also does not appear to be a caching issue, as I removed caching from the FormRevision object and the problem persists.

Strangest of all, if you debug the code, the first `formRevisionDao.findOne(id)` will return null.  However, subsequent identical calls will return the expected object.

I'm not sure what else could be causing this.  Maybe a synchronization or Hibernate version issue (currently using Hibernate 4.1.12 and using it with "Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production")?

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *formRevisionDao.findOne(id) is returning null for certain form revisions. This does not happen for every form revision, but for the ones it does happen for it is consistent, and will fail every time.* That's a pretty strong indication that there is no form revision with the given ID in the database. Check that you're using the database you think you're using.

Comment: @JBNizet I double-checked and the connection settings are correct.  Also, If I set a break point on `formRevision.fillLazyCollections()` I will see the object for `formRevisionDao.findOne(id)` in a watch but the `formRevision` variable will be null.  If I set a debug on `FormRevision formRevision = ..` my identical watch will be `null`, but stepping over that line the `formRevision` variable will not be.  Thus it seems the object is in the database associated with that DAO, but for some reason it is not finding it the first time.

Comment: I have a similar issue that I'm researching now. The data exists, it works for most IDs,  but not for a few where findOne(id) returns null. The workaround we have is to define the query in the repo and forgo use of findOne(id) in lieu of a custom findOneById(id).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring Data doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findOne(ID)), findOne:

> Returns:the entity with the given id or null if none found
>
> Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if id is null

So it only returns null when no entry is found. Being consistent and always returning null reinforces the conclusion that no record was found. Take the same db credentials and open an SQL console and check the missing record query.

Comment: I tested externally, and the exact query returns results with the same connection settings.